# Trouble with changing the output to reflect bubble sorting

Tags: c++, arrays, function, bubble-sort

I have a project I have been working on and I am horribly lost when it comes to how bubble sorting and everything else comes into play. I have to make my output look like the score chart in the comment portion. I've done part of it but have gotten lost. When it comes to bubble sorting and void functions I get a little lost. I know that void functions are not supposed to return anything unless called in the main but I still get confused on it a little. That and the way arrays play into things as well. Can anyone explain how to fix my code? Right now I'm just trying to get the scores to be displayed from greatest to least. So my bubble sorting needs to make it decrease.

```
   //******************************************************************************
    // Programmer:
    // Course:
    // Program:
// Date:
// Description: This program generates a standings report for the Premier League as of Nov 2017.
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Premier League, Nov 26 2017
// Club                      Pts   Wins  Draws
// -----------------------------------------
//  1 Manchester City     37    12   1
//  2 Manchester United   29    9    2
//  3 Chelsea             26    8    2
//  4 Arsenal             25    8    1
//  :
//  :
// 18 West Ham            10    2    4
// 19 Swansea              9    2    3
// 20 Crystal Palace       8    2    2
//
//******************************************************************************
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>    // for setw()
using namespace std;

// prototypes
void computePoints(int wins[], int draws[], int points[], int size);
// Receives the number of wins and draws for each club and computes their total points.

void sort(int points[], string club[], int wins[], int draws[], int size);
// Sorts the given arrays based on the points into decreasing order of points.

void swap(int & x, int & y);
// Swaps the integers x and y.

void swap(string & x, string & y);
// Swaps the strings x and y.

void printStandings(string club[], int wins[], int draws[], int points[], int size);
// Prints a table for the current standings.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
  const int SIZE = 20;    // number of clubs
  string club[SIZE] = {"Arsenal", "Bournemouth", "Brighton", "Burnley", "Chelsea", "Crystal Palace", "Everton", "Huddersfield", "Leicester", "Liverpool", "Manchester City", "Manchester United", "Newcastle", "Southampton", "Stoke City", "Swansea City", "Tottenham", "Watford", "West Bromwich", "West Ham"};
  int wins[SIZE] =  {8, 4, 4, 6, 8, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 12, 9, 4, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 2, 2};
  int draws[SIZE] = {1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5,  1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4 };
  int points[SIZE];

  // compute the points for each club (function call)
  computePoints(wins, draws, points, SIZE);
      for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    { 
      cout << points[i] << endl;
    }
cout << endl;  
  // sort all club data into decreasing order of points (function call)
sort(points, club, wins, draws, SIZE);
     for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    { 
      cout << points[i] << endl;
    }
  // print the standings (function call)
// printStandings(points, club, wins, draws, SIZE);
  return 0;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// implementation
void computePoints(int wins[], int draws[], int points[], int SIZE)
{

  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
 {

  points[i] = (wins[i] * 3) + draws[i] * 1;

 }


}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void sort(int points[], string club[], int wins[], int draws[], int SIZE)
{
  // bubble sort algorithm (see lesson-24)
  // Note: when swapping points[i] and points[i+1], the same elements in arrays club, wins, and
  // draws must be swapped. 

int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < j; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < j-i-1; ++j)
        {
            // Comparing consecutive data and switching values if value at j > j+1.
            if (points[j] > points[j+1])
            {
                points[j] = points[j]+points[j+1];
                points[j+1] = points[j]-points[j + 1];
                points[j] = points[j]-points[j + 1];
            }
        }
        // Value at j-i-1 will be maximum of all the values below this index.
    } 
    for(int points = SIZE + 1; points > 0; points--);    
    { 
      for(int i = 0;  i > points[i];  i++)  //make one pass & compare adjacent elements      
      { 
        if(points[i] >= points[i+1])  //if adjacent pairs are out of order, swap them.   

          swap(points[i], points[i+1]);      
      }   
    } 
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void swap(int & x, int & y)
{
  int temp = x; 
  x = y;
  y = temp;

}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void swap(string & x, string & y)
{
 string temp = x;
 x = y;
 y = temp;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void printStandings(string club[], int wins[], int draws[], int points[], int SIZE)
{
// output the heading
cout << "Premier League, Nov 26 2017" << endl;

// output the corresponding elements of all four arrays


}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I am sympathetic to your problems but you need to follow some rules and guidelines here on SO. Your question is a bit too unclear and broad. As it stands it reads as "help me with my code". We'd love to, but you need to be **specific**. Identify one issue you are having and create a [mcve] for it and ask it. Then your question has the expected output, but it lacks the actual output you have. And this circles back to the first issue: you need a ask a clear specific problem.

Comment: "void functions are not supposed to return anything unless called in the main" False. they are not supposed to return anything. Period. No *unless* or *except* clause.

Comment: very important: turn on your compiler warnings, and preferably treat them as errors, especially since you are learning. You will get some very helpful diagnostics, like using unitialized variables.

Comment: second very important: this is a problem that can be easily solved, or at least drastically narrowed down by **debugging**. Please take the time to learn how to use a debugger. It's immensely helpful and will you save you many hours of just staring at your code. I cannot stress enough how important is to able to debug your own code. Learn it sooner rather than later!

Answer (score 0):

From the start of your `sort`

```
// Note: when swapping points[i] and points[i+1], the same elements in arrays club, wins, and
// draws must be swapped.
```

There is *no mention* of `club`, `wins`, `draws` in your `sort` implementation.

Further, the first loop has *undefined behaviour*, the first time round `for (i = 0; i < j; ++i)`, `j` has not been initialised, so the compiler can omit the whole function, or do *anything else it wants*.

If you fix that, then in the inner first loop, `j < j-i-1` is always false, because `i` is always `0` or higher.

The second loop isn't valid syntax, because you reuse the name `points` for the loop index, and then use it like an array. 
You also start it *two* beyond the end of the input arrays, you want to start with `SIZE-1` if you want to access the element at `points[index]`.

```
void sort(int points[], string club[], int wins[], int draws[], int SIZE)
{
  // bubble sort algorithm (see lesson-24)
  // Note: when swapping points[i] and points[i+1], the same elements in arrays club, wins, and
  // draws must be swapped. 
    for (int i = SIZE - 1; i; --i) // stops when i is 0, as only 0 converts to false
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) // loop from 0 to i
        {
            // do comparison and swap all the necessary values
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you *must* use those function signatures, you probably should use a `struct result { std::string club; int wins; int draws; int points; }` and operate on a collection of `result`s. Preferably `std::vector<result> results;`